# How to write non-english characters to HttpResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, character-encoding, httpresponse

I am having problems in writing some Chinese characters to http response. I set application/vnd.ms-excel to ContentType.

When I view the excel file, I can't see the characters that I have written. I have tried using different encoding as well but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpResponse response = Page.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.GetEncoding("GB2312");
        response.Charset = "GB2312";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfile.xls");
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=GB2312";
        response.Write("盈亏 你好你好你怎么样");
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }
```

Comment: What's your editor's charset, if it is not gb2312, you have to convert it.

Comment: Is `盈亏 你好你好你怎么样` a valid Excel format?

Comment: Where, exactly, are you viewing the "Excel" file? Because, I'm willing to bet that those characters do not constitute a valid `xls` spreadsheet.

Comment: We managed to solve it by using BinaryWrite instead of Write in response. @M.Babcock we got excel file with this text once we receive the http-response in browser..

Comment: @MikeCaron, it appears that Excel is very forgiving. If I paste that text into notepad and save it as a .xls Excel will still open the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to solve it by using Response.BinaryWrite instead of Response.Write. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try put this in `web.config`

`<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8" />`

then output as UTF8